# Correlated Subquery not having expected behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have this SQL query in Postgres and I am having an unexpected behavior with it:

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT s.id,
  (
    SELECT string_agg(CAST(t_code AS TEXT), ',') 
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ps.status
      FROM products_status ps
      WHERE
        ps.status_transition_message_id IS NOT NULL AND 
        ps.enabled IS FALSE AND
        ps.status_transition_message_id = stm_rejected.id
    ) AS t_code
  ) AS t_code
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY stm.shipment_id ORDER BY date) AS rn 
  FROM status_transition_message stm
  WHERE
    stm.final_status = 6 OR
    stm.final_status = 7
) AS stm_rejected
JOIN shipment s ON s.id = stm_rejected.shipment_id
WHERE
  stm_rejected.rn = 1 AND
  stm_rejected.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate;
```

The `status_transition_message` table represents status transitions between X and Y for a given shipment. With this query, I am going through all shipments and getting those which had their 1st status transition to 6 or 7 (they can go through the same transition multiple times) between a given start and end date. For the shipments that respect this condition, I am doing a `SELECT` for the `t_code` field of `products_status` specified in that status transition.

The problem with this query is that in the `t_code` subquery, even when `ps.status_transition_message_id IS NOT NULL` evaluates to false, Postgres is still evaluating `ps.status_transition_message_id = stm_rejected.id`, even though it comes after an AND boolean operator. I know this is happening because when i remove the `ps.status_transition_message_id = stm_rejected.id` part from the query, it executes much faster. And I am also 100% sure that every `products_status` in the database that i am testing with has the `status_transition_message_id` as NULL.

EDIT: Here's how a `status_transition_message` row looks like:

```sql
[id] [date]         [initial_status]  [final_status]    [shipment_id]

434  3/20/13 14:18   0                4                  943
```

and a `products_status` row:

```sql
[id] [status]  [status_transition_message_id]  [enabled]    [shipment_id]

211  5         434                             true          943
```

The `status_transition_message_id` in the `products_status` table is a foreign key to the `status_transition_message` table, and this field can be null, which is why in the first clause of the `WHERE` statement of the subquery I am checking whether it is NULL or not (so it doesn't have to be tested against `stm_rejected` rows without need)

I don't know if it was clear in my question, but the query does the return the expected results. The problem is that it is unnecessarily evaluating AND clauses when the first one already evaluates to false, which is harming the query's performance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation would really benefit.

Comment: check out my edit and see if there's anything else you need

Comment: What is the purpose of the `string_agg()` function without a `group by` clause?

Comment: Because there's no need to group by. For every `stm_rejected` row, the `WHERE` clause of the subquery makes sure it only gets the `products_status` rows corresponding to the `stm_rejected.id`, and then aggregates the `t_code` of all of them

Comment: You're right. It looks like you're implicitly doing a join and group by via the correlated subquery. I'm going to suggest a different approach in my answer and hope that has a positive impact on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct: boolean expressions are not evaluated left-to-right. The [expression evaluation rules (4.2.14)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-expressions.html) in the postgres docs state:

> The order of evaluation of subexpressions is not defined. In particular, the inputs of an operator or function are not necessarily evaluated left-to-right or in any other fixed order.

To force evaluation order you can use a common table expression (CTE), which will also make your query more readable. It tells the optimizer to not rewrite the expression, but materialize the results instead, kind of like a temp table. It's hard to tell without running and explaining the query on your actual data whether it will result in performance improvement or degradation. I would try out both sub-queries and CTEs.

In your particular case, however, there may not be a need for a correlated sub-query. I've rewritten the query to use an inner join, which should handle that logic more efficiently. I'm also using a CTE here, but for a different purpose, because my guess is that the transition to status 6 and 7 are a tiny subset of all transitions, and so performance may benefit from that early reduction of rows.

I also went out on a limb here and changed the logic to replace the distinct with an explicit grouping.

```sql
with

  stm_rejected as (
    select
      id,
      "date" as transition_date,
      row_number() over (partition by shipment_id order by "date") as transition_rank
    from
      status_transition_message
    where
      final_status in (6, 7)
  )

select
  shipment.id as shipment_id,
  string_agg(products_status.t_code, ',') as t_codes
from
  shipment
  inner join stm_rejected
    on shipment.id = stm_rejected.shipment_id
  inner join products_status
    on stm_rejected.id = products_status.status_transition_message_id
where
  stm_rejected.transition_rank = 1
  and stm_rejected.transition_date between :startDate and :endDate
  and products_status.enabled = false
group by
  shipment.id
;
```

Comment: Wow, what an amazing and complete answer! I did find it strange how the boolean operators were getting evaluated and tried to think of another way of rewriting the query, but couldn't come up with anything. I will try your solutions out tomorrow and mark the question answered if it works. Thank you :)